# How to make strings unique by certain parameters in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Example: Let's say we have a friends table with columns user_id, friend_id, status. We need to be able to add:

| user_id | friend_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | False |
| 3 | 2 | False |
| 3 | 4 | False |

But it was impossible to add:

| user_id | friend_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | False |
| 2 | 3 | False |
| 4 | 3 | False |

In other words, so that IDs 1 and 2, 1 and 3 can be added and their reflections 2 and 1, 3 and 1 cannot be added.

Thank you in advance

I tried to make a composite key of user_id and friend_id consisting of foreign keys referencing to the same table. I also tried. I also tried to make these values unique, but in this case I can't add duplicates; for example 1 and 2, 1 and 3 (not added).

Comment: To put it another way, you want to make sure that friend relationships are unique? If 1 is friends with 3, then 3 cannot be friends with 1. And 1 cannot be friends with 1.

Comment: Rihgt. If 3 confirms friendship with 1, then there is no need to add row 3 and 1 to the table
Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike most many-to-many associations, this one is bidirectional. Both members are peers.

You can prevent a user from being friends with themselves with a check: `check(user_id <> friend_id)`.

You can prevent duplicate friend relationships with a unique index on an expression that does not care about the order. For example, make an array and [sort it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html).

```
create extension intarray;

create unique index on friends(
  (sort(array[user_id, friend_id]))
)
```

User ID 3 / Friend ID 1 and User ID 1 / Friend ID 3 both result in `[1, 3]`.

To get a complete list of a user's friends you need to search by both user_id and friend_id.

```
select count(*)
from friends
where user_id = $1 or friend_id = $1
```

This suggests it might be better to refer to them as `friend1` and `friend2` making the point that the relationship is bidirectional.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/icApip--).